# The state of being melancholic is called melancholia. What are similar words for other 3 Graeco-Roman temperaments?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, sentence-patterns

Melancholic -> melancholia
Choleric -> ??
Sanguine -> ??
Phlegmatic -> ??

Comment: The word _choler_ exists, and Merriam-Webster claims that _sanguineness_ is a word. There doesn't appear to be one for 'being phlegmatic'.

Comment: Agree about choler. Cambridge Dictionary says: phlegm noun [U] (CALMNESS)
 
formal
the ability to stay calm and not get emotional or excited about things even in a difficult or dangerous situation

Comment: cholerous or cholerics, phlegmatic(s) or mucusy and sanguineous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choleric >> Choler

Sanguine >> Sanguinity/Sanguineness

Phlegmatic >> Phlegmaticness

None of them is as cool as malancholia, but there you go.